# How to install Windows 7 inside Oracle Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit) on a 64-bit machine.
I want to install Windows 7 64-bit inside virtualbox. I have
enabled virtualization in the bios. I have installed oracle
virtualbox with the latest .deb from oracle. I am able to
create .vdi (virtual disk images) and .vhd (virtual hard
drives) on my system. I have root access. I also have the
Windows 7 recovery disk. I do not have a Windows 7 disk
image of a snapshot of windows 7 on the same PC. I do
have a windows recovery partition on disk, but it
seems this one is not accessible by virtualbox.

How do I install Windows 7 64-bit inside Ubuntu?

Comment: This Question is considered Off-Topic as per community policy: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2425/wheres-the-off-topic-line

Answer (score 1):

**The only safe way to install Windows 7 in Virtual Box is to use an installation CD (or a CD image).**

Depending on your licence it may allow you to use the Windows licence from your PC for the virtual machine, provided you do not have installed Windows outside the virtual machine. If you have such a license you will be able to install Windows from any other installation CD. You will not need the physical data from your recovery partition.

As in theory it is possible to bind a hard drive as raw disk to Virtual Box (see the [Virtual Box manual on how to do this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk)) this may not be a good idea when it comes to data security. In addition to that it is very doubtful that if you booted your recovery partition or recovery CD it will install anywhere else but the machine it was built for.