# Can I use ISO image to install Win 7 in VirtualBox running on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Windows 7 inside Oracle Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166830/how-to-install-windows-7-inside-oracle-virtualbox)

Attempting to install Win 7 from ISO image in VirtualBox installed on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS.
The image boots but fails to continue install. I've tried 2 ISO images with the same result.

How should I change what I'm doing for a successful install?

Comment: Could you provide us with more information on what errors you might be receiving - is it an Ubuntu related error or a Windows related one? Also, could you check if the images that you're using work fine?

Answer (score 3):

You can of course use Windows 7 iso image to install it in the Virtual Box, regardless of using Ubuntu or any other operating system. Ubuntu doesn't impose any restriction to that, as you may have assumed.

Check the iso images first whether they are bootable or even valid. Also make sure you configured the VirtualBox to use the iso file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check the two ISO I have downloaded.I do not know how to configure Vbox to use ISO. That option does not appear in GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I would also check to make sure that your hardware can install 64bit OSes as a guest, you will need [hardware extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Hardware_assist) enabled to do so.

It is not difficult to enable hardware extensions if your processor supports it, you will have to let us know what the processor is.

This answer will provide you with more information: https://askubuntu.com/a/184376/92882

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was successful My ISO image was corrupt. I also changed the bios of my laptop to allow foe VMs.

Answer (score 0):

follow the [following link](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-on-virtualbox/) it is helpfull with screenshots. If it fits your answer I will edit my answer and insert step by step guide with pictures

Note: Check your ISO image and remake it (or download is again)

Comment: The link was helpful in a successful install of WIN 7.My version of Virtualbox recognized the install was an ISO image automatically.